# Bloomreach: Show neat 404 page in case of non-existing static file

Tags: http-status-code-404, hippocms

In the sitemap I have arranged that a neat 404 page is shown for non-existing pages. This neat page is not shown when I access a non-existing url in the static folder. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

On the top level in your sitemap you need to add an *any* matcher that points to the 404 page.

see also:
https://documentation.bloomreach.com/14/library/concepts/error-pages-and-error-handling/2.-add-a-catch-all-sitemap-item-that-creates-a-dynamic-404-page.html